# Voting on the meta

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, up-votes

This is an announcement/notice about the meaning of voting on the meta.

- **Up** generally means **I agree**
- **Down** generally means **I disagree**

This is a subtle difference with the main site. One should not be surprised when a question or answer is down voted on the meta. It simply means that somebody has disagreed.

Of course in extreme circumstances it still carries its meaning of low quality. Especially for very low quality posts. Do not be discouraged to vote.

Vote, vote and vote!

Comment: I completely agree.

Comment: This is true sometimes, but not always, which is unfortunately one of the most confusing aspects of meta. Specifically, it's usually true for [tag:feature-request] posts, and often true for [tag:discussion] answers and some [tag:discussion] questions. It's rarely true for [tag:support] and [tag:bug]. Generally speaking, if the post contains an opinion, people vote based on whether they agree or disagree, but if it doesn't it's based on the post quality (e.g. for bugs, reproduceability and accurate description of the issue).

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of votes on meta is what we decide for them to mean. Some sites operate as said in OP but not all; or at least to quite different degrees as already said in some sense by Logan Maingi.

I certainly agree that down-votes on meta can and should be cast a lot more freely, but the "downvote express disagree" idea is in my opinion somewhat problematic for several reasons (I only give the most clear-cut one) especially when combined with a call to vote a lot.

Suppose I write: "I think we should do X  only in case condition Y is met."

Then A  thinking  we should do X always and N thinking we should never do X, both disagree with me while having completely contradictory views.

So what a downvote on "I think we should do X only in case condition Y is met" really means is anybodies guess. (This is not some contrived example, I got dv on posts I consider middle-of-the-road positions where I had and have no idea in which direction the dissent was.)